# What is David's Salary per month?

Tags: percentages, ratio

John and David's salary adds upto 10,000 $ per month. They spend the same amount monthly and then it is found that ratio of their savings in 6:!. Which of the following is John's salary

6000 , 5000 , 4000 , 3000

I have tried this question but i have two unknowns and 1 equation left with me. due to which i am unable to solve the question.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were not given the choices, there would not be enough information to solve the problem.  You could have John make $5000+x$, David make $5000-x$ and expenses be $5000-1.4x$ and meet the problem statement.  Given the choices, John must make more than David to have greater savings, and only $6000$ allows that.

Comment: how did you come up with value of expenses

Comment: I used the $6:1$ ratio of savings.  If David saves $y$, John saves $6y$, so we have $6y=2x+y, y=0.4x$.  David saves $0.4x$ and John saves $2.4x$